# Evaluate a list of functions in R all with the same input and return list of arrays or matrix

Tags: r

Say you have a list of functions

```
funList=list()
for (i in 1:5){
    funList[[i]]=approxfun(0:5,(0:5)^i,method="linear", rule=2)
}
```

and later you want a matrix of values with each row (or column which ever makes the code simpler or even a list of arrays instead of a matrix would be fine) being of the form of lets say

```
funList[[i]](1:3)
```

I've tried using lapply, but I haven't been able to get that to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `do.call`:

```
lapply(funList, do.call, list(1:3))
```

You can replace `eval.with.args` in all of @flodel's examples with `do.call` if you wrap the second argument in an additional call to `list`.

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
eval.with.args <- function(FUN, ...) FUN(...)
```

Then one of:

```
lapply(funList, eval.with.args, 1:3)
sapply(funList, eval.with.args, 1:3)
mapply(eval.with.args, funList, list(1:3))
Map(eval.with.args, funList, list(1:3))
```

I think I remember asking on the forums if there was a function that already implemented `function(FUN, ...)FUN(...)` but the answer was "no" at the time. It could make a nice addition to the `base` or `functional` packages IMHO.

Comment: This is great! I'm going to leave the question open for a little bit, just in case "I think I remember asking on the forums if there was a function that already implemented function(FUN, ...)FUN(...) but the answer was "no" at the time." there might be one now.